# Calling multiple oracle stored procedure in java and maintaining data consistency

Tags: java, exception, java-stored-procedures

This method has some issues I failed to understand, such as it doesn't rollback the changes made in previous procedure call if any of the procedure calls down the hierarchy throws an exception.... Please help me out

```
public synchronized boolean save(DTO dto) throws DAOException,IllegalArgumentException
{           boolean retVal=false;
            boolean retVal1=false;
            boolean retVal2=false;
            boolean retVal5=true;
    try{
                connection=dataSource.getConnection();
                connection.setAutoCommit(false);
                cstmt=connection.prepareCall("{call PKG_ALL.PROC_MAIN(?,?,?)}");

                cstmt.setString(1, "A");     cstmt.setString(2, "B");
                cstmt.registerOutParameter(3,Types.VARCHAR);

                ResultSet rs=cstmt.executeQuery();                  
                String ErrMsg=cstmt.getString(3);
                if(ErrMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Record Inserted"))  retVal=true;
                else retVal=false;

        cstmt.close();

        cstmt1=connection.prepareCall("{call PKG_ALL.PROC_CHILD1(?,?,?)}");

                cstmt1.setString(1, "A");     cstmt1.setString(2, "B");
                cstmt1.registerOutParameter(3,Types.VARCHAR);

                ResultSet rs1=cstmt.executeQuery();                 
                String ErrMsg1=cstmt1.getString(3);
                if(ErrMsg1.equalsIgnoreCase("Record Inserted")) retVal1=true;
                else retVal1=false;

        cstmt1.close();

        if(strSerialNo!=null && strSerialNo.length > 0) // for a non-mandatory multirow in the form
        {  
            cstmt2=connection.prepareCall("{call PKG_ALL.PROC_CHILD2(?,?,?)}");
                for(int k=0;k<strSerialNo.length;k++)
                    {
                        cstmt2.setString(1,"M");
                        cstmt2.setString(2,"I");
                        cstmt2.registerOutParameter(3,Types.VARCHAR);

                        ResultSet rs2=cstmt2.executeQuery();
                        String ErrMsg2=cstmt2.getString(3);
                        if(ErrMsg2.equalsIgnoreCase("Record Inserted")) retVal2=true;
                        else
                            {
                                retVal5=false;
                                retVal2=false;
                            }           
                    } 
            cstmt2.close();
        }   

        **if(retVal&&retVal1&&retVal5)**
                {
                    retVal=true;
                    connection.commit();
                }
                else
                {
                    //connection.rollback();
                    retVal=false;
                }
    }
    catch(SQLException e)
            {
                throw new DAOException(":"+e.getMessage());
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new DAOException(":"+e.getMessage());

            }
            finally
            {
                closeConnection(connection);
            }
            return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> it doesn't rollback the changes made in previous procedure call if any of the procedure calls down the hierarchy throws an exception

Ofc, you don't put the call to rollback in the catch SQLException block. You only call the rollback method if one of your request doesn't work WITHOUT throwing an exception.

Also you never commit changes after executing your requests so when you come to the else statement where you call `connection.rollback();`, you actually have nothing to rollback because nothing has been commited.

Read [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html) to have a basic example of how to handle commit/rollback.

Comment: Please tell me what will the missing code be like..@alain.janinm

Comment: @user1728387 You can use connection.commit(); after each query. Then in catch blocks you add connection.rollback(); And you can get rid of your condition if(retVal&&retVal1&&retVal5)